# C++ idiomatic way for nullable reference

Tags: c++, reference, nullable

I am writing a function which should accept `const std::string &`, but also a special `nullptr` value. Currently, I'm using `const std::string *`. However, I feel that there should be a more C++-ish way to perform this task.

My strongest counterpoint is passing by value (the string won't be really long but 64kB is not something I want copied around). That also implies that I want no object like `optional<T>` which would have a value field of type `T`. Also, I don't want to use any external libraries. My project is not using Boost or GSL, just plain C++ (C++17 to be exact).

Is there a standard library class (miracles occur in `namespace std`) or a widely accepted idiom for such situation?

Comment: FWIW, `boost::optional` supports references, but `std::optional` does not. That would be the place you'd expect it.

Comment: What's wrong with std::optional? It gives you the exact functionality you want

Comment: @chris although I know the position of Boost as The Second Standard Library, I am trying to avoid using it unless I need something more than just ``boost::optional``

Comment: @GabrielAlexander it does not support references because they're not ``Destructible``

Comment: I'm not suggesting you need to use Boost, it just makes for a nice contrast point, especially given Boost's standardization history in general.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that was supposed to be about a string view. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @TopSekret Oh, right, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `std::optional` supported references, it'd be the fancy "modern" way to do this.

But:

- it doesn't, and
- sometimes being fancy and "modern" is not all that it is cracked up to be.

The age-old, tried-and-tested and clear-to-read solution is to take a pointer. This approach does absolutely everything that you need it to do.

Just do that, then move on to spend your precious time on more important matters!

Comment: The last paragraph is the wisest thing I've heard today

Answer (score 3):

An interesting aspect of this question is that I've more commonly seen the reverse perspective: what is the C++ way to specify a pointer that is not allowed to be null? The answers come down to the same principles.

The main differences between a pointer a reference are:

1. A pointer can be made to point to a different object.
2. A pointer can be null.

If you make the pointer constant, the first difference goes away. The C++ way to have a "nullable reference" is to have a constant pointer. Note that I am talking about the pointer being constant, as in `T * const`, which is independent of the pointed-to object being constant, as in `T const *` or `const T *`.

You might have been trained to think that all pointers are evil, but that is an over-generalization. Raw pointers are a fine way to refer to optional objects *whose memory you are **not** responsible for*. If you are responsible for releasing memory, use a smart pointer, but if someone else is holding the memory for you, use a reference or a pointer. Use a reference if the object is required (cannot be null); a pointer if it is optional (can be null). Oh, this assumes you do not need to change which object is pointed-to, in which case a reference would no longer be an option.

That being said, there might be alternatives in specific contexts. If there is no code shared between the null and not-null cases, it might be better to have overloaded functions, something like `void foo(const std::string &)` and `void foo()`. This has to be balanced against various trade-offs, including API consistency. Go with what works best for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

As you have specifically asked for some STD library miracle: The STD library actually features a `reference_wrapper` that can be combined with `optional` to somewhat achieve what you are asking for:

```
template <class T>
using optional_ref = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>;
```

It`s actually pretty straight forward but also a bit cumbersone to access:

```
void foo(optional_ref<std::string> str)
{
    if (str)
        printf("%s", str->get().c_str());
}
```

From the calling site it works pretty nice:

```
std::string str;
foo(str); // passes a reference
foo({}); // passes nothing
```

Having said that, I also don't think it is a good idea to use ;) (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to provide an empty string that your function can detect via object identity checks:

```
#include <string>

namespace MyLibrary
{
   static const std::string NULL_STRING;

   void foo(const std::string& str)
   {
      if (&str == &NULL_STRING)
         // ...
      else
         // ...
   }
}

int main()
{
   MyLibrary::foo("Hello, world!");
   MyLibrary::foo("");

   MyLibrary::foo(MyLibrary::NULL_STRING);
}
```

One might consider this to be a bit of a waste of space, though, and I don't consider it to be particularly idiomatic. However, I have taken a similar approach inside private library code, on occasion (particularly coupled with default arguments).

Comment: Bonus alternative answer because I have never been good at spending my precious time on more important matters ;)

Comment: Should the ``NULL_STRING`` constant in your approach be per-function, per-library or per-environment?

Comment: @TopSekret I'd make it per-library most likely but it depends on too many things to say generally. It's always a bit of a hack anyway

Answer (score -1):

Write two functions:

```
void f(const string *s)
{
    if (s)
    {
        // Use s
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't use s
    }
}

void f(const string &s)
{
    f(&s);
}
```

Comment: I think function variants with x and a pointer to x are a big no-no because they make the use of ``&`` and ``*`` ambiguous and messy.

Comment: @TopSekret, I'm unable to make sense out of that statement.  What are you talking about ?

Comment: If both ``f(x)`` and ``f(&x)`` are perfectly valid and both ``f(y)`` and ``f(*y)`` are perfectly valid, one may start to lose track of whether ``x`` is ``string`` or ``string*``, the same for ``y``

Comment: I agree it's confusing to have functions with the same name that take `T&` and `T*` respectively.

Comment: It's added cognitive load, particularly if your callsite already requires a dereference for whatever reason. Why have the reference overload? What's the point?

Comment: @SidS if ``x`` is a ``string*`` but you only do ``f(x)``, then you may forget if ``x`` is a ``string`` or ``string*`` as both work in such case.

Comment: @TopSekret, I don't see what the problem is.  I want to pass `x` to a function and that's what I do.  It doesn't matter whether `x` is a `string` or a `string *` - the outcome is the same.

Comment: It does matter, because every decision you make requires a quantity of thought and research into what the functions do. You've doubled-up on that, for no gain at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, "Why have the reference overload ?"  Because it is one way to do what he was asking how to do.

Comment: "Because you can" is not a valid answer to my question, Sid. Explain why the OP _should_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I didn't say "because you can."  I said "because it is an answer to his question".

Comment: Guess you don't want to (or can't) explain why this approach is good, then. No worries :)